# Vite React app HashRouter not work on github pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, github-pages, vite

I built an app with vite react router. I pushed it to github pages and got some error. I read about github pages doesn't support browserrouter, so I changed it to hashrouter, but still not working. This is the code for it.

```html
import React from 'react';
import { HashRouter as HashRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage';
import HeroesPage from './pages/HeroesPage';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route path="/HeroesPage" element={<HeroesPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </HashRouter>
  );
}
```

Maybe I made mistakes when use hashrouter. I dont know where I should start search for the mistake. Is there any issue with the way I imported and implemented hashrouter or the path?

Comment: Your code looks right to me, heres CodeSandbox in action https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-tu-rff52p?file=/src/App.tsx Can you provide more info? such as what error you are seeing.

Comment: I got 404 error, There isn't a GitHub Pages site here. Strangely when I tried it first, it actually load a page, but it was one of my previous projects what I pushed to github pages, but in another repository, completly separated. That the reason I think I have issue with the path.

Comment: We can look more if  you wouldn't mind sharing repo

Comment: Actually I solved it this morning. thanks for the code sandbox you provided. The problem was the link in the navbar. I used <a> tag for it instead of Link. I saw you use Link and change it :)